# wcf net.tcp using SSL

Tags: wcf, security, ssl, net.tcp

Has anyone had experience using SSL with net.tcp binding in WCF?

Ive read its possible, but not finding good information on how to implement it.  I would love to hear from anyone who knows about or who has implemented this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at the contents in this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011.aspx

especially the section on "To use the NetTcpBinding with a certificate for transport security"