# WCF self hosted HTTPS with custom UserNamePasswordValidator

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have a WCF service which is running fine.

- It is used within an intranet network.
- It is a self-hosted service
  (no IIS) managed by a simple Windows Form program.
- It is used by a
  WCF client (WPF C#).

I now need to add security to it and after having read a lot of posts on the internet I'm getting confused as there are many ways of doing.

I need a custom username and password validator (I will have to call another web service to know if user is authorized or not).
I also need secure communication between client and server.

I am currently using basicHttpBinding.
MS recommends the use of NetTcpBinding in my case (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx#TransportSecurityWCF), but I am not sure if this is or can be secured ?

I think I better use WsHttpBinding to have SSL: do you think that this link provides proper solution to my case ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775.aspx ?

Thanks for your advices

Comment: Any code to show?  Since your project is for an intranet `NetTcpBinding` is the best approach and it **can be made secure**. [Tell me more](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-WCF-Services-Mastering-AppFabric/dp/0596805489)

Comment: possible duplicate of [wcf net.tcp using SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455251/wcf-net-tcp-using-ssl)

Comment: thanks for your first answers. I have some code, but useless to show here as it is a very simple WCF basic HTTP service.

Comment: I will have a look at the possible duplicate link, on thursday when I'm back to work. Sounds very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do SSL/Transport encryption with BasicHTTPBinding. That doesn't need to change; you just need to set up the host side with "Transport" security, add some code and a certificate, and you should be able to proceed without changing too much code. I can include a small code sample below, since I did the same thing you're trying to do via a self-hosted service.

```
BasicHttpBinding b = default(BasicHttpBinding);
if (bUseSSL) {
  //check for ssl msg credential bypass
    if (bSSLMsgCredentialBypass) {
      b = new   BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
    } else {
      b = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
    }

    b.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
    b.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
    b.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
    b.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    b.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
    //b.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
}
```

The authentication/authorization can be done, too, without changing what you currently have. You really have two choices:

One is that you create a Login function that get's called when the client first visits the host. You then send some token value back to the client for all subsequent communications.

The other way involves creating that custom authentication check, using the message inspector functionality found in Dispatcher.IDispatchMessageInspector and a public function called AfterReceiveRequest. Within that function, you can examine the UserID and Pwd (from within the HTTP header data) sent from the clients- but you need to implement this on both the client and host sides, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am finally using this solution : http://leastprivilege.com/2007/10/31/finally-usernames-over-transport-authentication-in-wcf/ (found on some other places too). I only had issues adding SSL, but finally managed after a whole day of labor!